# Does clipping in openGL pipeline happen before or after primitive assembly?

Tags: opengl, graphics

Firstly, I'm not entirely sure how the clipping works, but I suppose it "cuts" off the fragments that are not seen by the viewer, although I don't know how this works in practice. However, does it happen before or after the primitive assembly?

The [official documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive_Assembly) says this:

> The purpose of the primitive assembly step is to convert a vertex stream into a sequence of base primitives. For example, a primitive
>   which is a line list of 12 vertices needs to generate 11 line base
>   primitives.
>
> The full primitive assembly step (including the processing below) will
>   always happen after Vertex Post-Processing. However, some Vertex
>   Processing steps require that a primitive be decomposed into a
>   sequence of base primitives. For example, a Geometry Shader operates
>   on each input base primitive in the primitive sequence. Therefore, a
>   form of primitive assembly must happen before the GS can execute.
>
> This early primitive assembly only performs the conversion to base
>   primitives. It does not perform any of the below processing steps.
>
> Such early processing must happen if a Geometry Shader or Tessellation
>   is active. The early assembly step for Tessellation is simplified,
>   since Patch Primitives are always sequences of patches.

It seems that there are two forms of primitive assembly, which I'm confused about.

First, we see that when the vertex data is first fed into the vertex shader for rendering, it has to interepret the stream of vertices as some triangle or line etc.  This is called "rendering" I suppose.

But on the other hand, the primitive assembly as quoted above also does something so similar. What is the difference between the two processes?

The article on [primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) says this:

> The term Primitive in OpenGL is used to refer to two similar but
>   separate concepts. The first is the interpretive scheme used by OpenGL
>   to determine what a stream of vertices represents when being rendered.
>   Such sequences of vertices can be arbitrarily long.
>
> The other meaning of "Primitive" is as the result of the
>   interpretation of a vertex stream, as part of Primitive Assembly.
>   Therefore, processing a vertex stream by one of these primitive
>   interpretations results in an ordered sequence of primitives. The
>   individual primitives are sometimes called "base primitives".

If we follow the quote above, it seems that there is no difference between the two apparently separate concepts. The "interpretation step" can view, say, a sequence of 10 vertices as 8 dependent triangles. But so can the primitive assembly steps, which views the "dependent triangles" as base primitives. What is concretely different between the two?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, there are a lot of things called "primitive assembly". They all do the same thing (turn a sequence of vertices into individual primitives), but several of them happen at different times.

There is a specific chapter of the specification titled "Fixed-Function Primitive Assembly and Rasterization." One could argue that this is where "the" Primitive Assembly stage happens. But the standard also says that it happens after the VS, after the TES, and after the GS (where applicable).

The standard still talks about "the primitive assembly stage" as if there were only one, despite the fact that it clearly calls for multiple of them.

What's clear is that the process of clipping knows about the individual primitives, so some primitive assembly has happened prior to reaching that stage.

Answer (score 0):

I found something in the Specification of OpenGL Version 4.6 (Core Profile):

The output of Vertex Shader:

> If the output variables are passed directly to the vertex processing stages lead- ing to rasterization, the values of all outputs are expected to be interpolated across the primitive being rendered, unless flatshaded. Otherwise the values of all out- puts are collected by the primitive assembly stage and passed on to the subsequent pipeline stage once enough data for one primitive has been collected.

Seems that if there is no TES and GS, the "Primitive Assembly" will be done later. Otherwise where will be an "early primitive assembly " as said in official documentation.

However in "11.1.3 Shader Execution" of the specification：

> The following sequence of operations is performed:
>
> - Vertices are processed by the vertex shader (see section 11.1) and assembled into primitives as described in sections 10.1 through 10.3.
> - If the current program contains a tessellation control shader, each indi- vidual patch primitive is processed by the tessellation control shader (sec- tion 11.2.1). Otherwise, primitives are passed through unmodified. If active, the tessellation control shader consumes its input patch and produces a new patch primitive, which is passed to subsequent pipeline stages.
> - If the current program contains a tessellation evaluation shader, each indi- vidual patch primitive is processed by the tessellation primitive generator (section 11.2.2) and tessellation evaluation shader (see section 11.2.3). Oth- erwise, primitives are passed through unmodified. When a tessellation eval- uation shader is active, the tessellation primitive generator produces a new collection of point, line, or triangle primitives to be passed to subsequent pipeline stages. The vertices of these primitives are processed by the tes- sellation evaluation shader. The patch primitive passed to the tessellation primitive generator is consumed by this process.
> - If the current program contains a geometry shader, each individual primitive is processed by the geometry shader (section 11.3). Otherwise, primitives are passed through unmodified. If active, the geometry shader consumes its input patch primitive. However, each geometry shader invocation may emit new vertices, which are arranged into primitives and passed to subsequent pipeline stages.
>
> Following shader execution, the fixed-function operations described in chap- ter 13 are applied.

Have a look at the "fixed-function operations" in chapter 13, there will do all the "Vertex Post-processing" such as clipping, perspective-divide, viewport transform and Transform-feedback. In chapter 13, I found:

> After programmable vertex processing, the following fixed-function operations are applied to vertices of the resulting primitives:...

---

### My understand

I think the accurate time of "Primitive Assembly" happened maybe is a little hard to tell, but I tend to believe that this is done just after vertex process. As Nicol said *What's clear is that the process of clipping knows about the individual primitives, so some primitive assembly has happened prior to reaching that stage.*.

I think one of main task of the so-called "Primitive Assembly" stage which between vertex process and rasterization is  the *face culling*. (I am not familiar with multi-draw maybe this stage is to do with this too.)

---

### A figure of vertex process:

[image: vertex]

---

### A simple pipeline based on my simple understand:

```
# Start


(Vertices Data)
     |
     |
     |
     V
Vertex Shader   # Do primitive assembly here    
     |
     |
     | (primitives)
     |
     V
[Tessellation Shaders] 
     |
     |
     | (primitives)
     |
     V
[Geometry Shader]
     |
     |
     | (primitives)
     |
     V     
Vertex Post-processing
     |
     |
     | (primitives)
     |
     V    
Primitive Assembly  # Mainly do face culling
     |
     |
     | (primitives)
     |
     V    
Rasterization
     |
     |
     | (fragment)
     |
     V         
Fragment Shader

# [] means can be ignored
```